# Finding eigenvalues in MATLAB without using eig function

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

I'm trying to find eigenvalues of a matrix without using eig function (my homework says so). In Matlab, I define the matrix and identity matrix. But I cannot set up this equation:

```
A - x*I
```

x here is lambda, A is the matrix that I should find eigenvalues of and I is the identity matrix. If you know how to find eigenvalues, you supposed to understand this. How can I go through?

Comment: Have you [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm)?

Answer (score 3):

you can get some inspiration here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm

if the matrix is fixed size, you can easily do the `det(A-lambda*eye)=0` solving by yourself and use that.

With [power iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) you can already find the dominant eigenvalue, and I knew there was an extension to this algorithm to also find the other eigenvalues, but cannot recall how that works :(